# HighCharts - do not crop series line on max value

Tags: highcharts, highcharts-ng, angular2-highcharts

I've been digging through the highchairs api and can't seem to find anything, so who knows if it's possible.
 I have a graph that represents data as percentages - min and max are concrete at 0, 100 respectively. Linewidth is set at 2 and I've noticed that if values are at max, 100, the line stroke is cut off in the middle - making the line look awkwardly skinny / cramped at the top of the graph.
 Is there any property to add to `yAxis`, `series` or other that forces the full line stroke to draw?[image: h]

Answer (score 3):

It's `series.clip` - so close. 
set to false to disable clipping
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.clip